# Python's isfile() doesn't find a file that does exist from shell

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a block of code that tries to open an image file, but the Image.open fails - I added a isfile() check and it still fails to find the file when the python script is run.

However, the file does exist with ls from shell, or using the same path/file from the script in a python interpreter directly from shell.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

for x in range(0,10):

    file = work_dir + "/video" + str(x).zfill(4) + ".png"
    if os.path.isfile(file):
            print "file exists"
    else:
            print "file doesn't exit"

    print "opening file:" + file
    im = Image.open(file)
    im = im.resize((720,480))
    im = im.convert("RGBA")
    im.save(file)
```

Let's say work_dir = "/home/user"   it reports /home/user/video0000.png but isfile() doesn't find it even thought the file exists!  Is there something I am overlooking or a way to debug this?

Comment: `print file` should help make sure that you're checking the path you think you're checking.

Comment: what does `ls  | grep video*.png` output ? Also glob would probably be a better option

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Why is `grep` involved? `ls video*.png` would work directly via shell globbing, while `grep` would be... strange (the glob pattern would be expanded by the shell and passed as positional arguments to `grep`, or if no files exist, it might pass the raw pattern to `grep`, which would allow `videoooooooxpng` but not `video0000.png` because `*` and `.` are regex special characters). I agree the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) would simplify the code significantly.

Comment: What is `work_dir`? If the string already ends with a `/`, or you're on Windows, and it omits the drive letter (or it has the drive letter only, with no trailing slash), you'll be looking somewhere completely different. For safety/correctness, you probably want `file = os.path.join(work_dir, "video{:>04}.png".format(x))` (which also avoids extra temporary `str`s).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, a brain fart,  originally I was going to use a more specific pattern   `ls  |  grep -E 'video[0-9]{4}\.png'`

Comment: lets say work_dir = "/home/user/files"   Even when i hardcore the file name it still comes up with [Errno 2] No such file or directory when i execute the python script!

Comment: @FightFireWithFire, add the output of running ls or the grep -E command above when you are in home/user

Comment: @FightFireWithFire: You can't hand wave away the value of `work_dir` here; small issues (an errant `/`) would be enough to break your code; please add a `print work_dir` before the `is_file` test and provide the _exact_ path. If something is sensitive/private, change the text for that specific component, but do not change punctuation or anything else non-alphanumeric at all. It might also be useful to try `print repr(work_dir)`, in case you've got non-printing characters embedded (say, `\r` or `\n`; plain `print` won't show them, but converting to `repr` will fix that).

Comment: @ShadowRanger that is a great idea, I tried it with repr, I've also tried it executing the script with sudo to see if it was a permissions problem but to no avail. The script simply refuses to see this file that exists or not. I'll add some more code and maybe that will reveal the issue